# How to mention a user correctly?

Tags: python

```
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content.startswith('$hug'): # here I want the mention
        args = message.content.split(' ')
        if len(args) == 2:
            member: Member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: args[1] in m.name, message.guild.members)
            await message.channel.send('{} wurde umarmt <3'.format(member.name))
            await message.channel.send('{}'.format(random.choice(hug)))
```

How do I implement it so that when a user mentions someone in a message, this is then displayed in the response.

Sorry for my bad english